# How get last five unique rates of product based on month & year in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql-python

I have a table with following data

> [image: Blockquote]

I want last five rates of item based on month & year.

[image]

The logic behind it is that, if item price change in any particular month say two changes in a month it should be listed in a table as mentioned in example sample result row no 3 & 4 also other rates like in other month as well.

Can anybody help me out to get this in instantly.

I have just tried to get no of distinct value from the table as using following sql query:

"SELECT DISTINCT monthyear, itemname, rate FROM av_products_txn"

But I am not able to get last give as mentioned in sample result image.

Thanks in advance.

@Michel and @CBroe

[image]

Comment: I don't get your explanation of the desired result. Why for Sept-21 there is only the 45 in there, but for Aug-21 it is both 35 and 15?

Comment: If you want the last 5 per Month/Year shouldn't the Sample-Result show 3 values for `Sep-21` and 4 for `Aug-21`  ?

Comment: Also, how is `last 5` defined? By `id` or something else?

Comment: if we talk about last five unique rates then it will be taken as follows:                 15 abc 45 Oct-21 1
10 abc 35 Sep-21 2
8 abc 15 Aug-21 3
7 abc 35 Aug-21 4
4 abc 25 Jun-21 5
means if in particular month it rate is same as last it wont be considered like in the month of aug.

Comment: Please put your clarification in the question, not in a comment. It's hardly readable this way.

Comment: Apart from that this is hard to read in comments, I don't see how that _explains_ anything any better now. _"means if in particular month it rate is same as last it wont be considered"_ - so why does August get both its 35 and 15 into the result then, but September has only 35? The 45 gets skipped because it appears twice in direct succession, okay - but how does that explain, why the previous 27 is not in the result as well?

Comment: @CBore well previous 27 is a different product, I have put rates of two products in a table and given example of one product to understand in a better way. The login behind last five rates is the fetch the change or say to know the trend of change of rates in a respective month or year of a particular product.

Answer (score -1):

Design a database application using python gui to modify the specific record of product using pro _id  from database and display modifier record
Product table  (pro id, pro name, quantity)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).